# Pine-Script : Multi Price-Triggered Alert Error

Tags: pine-script

I'm working on the multi price triggered alert script, but the script has the error.

I'm doing the alert for the stop-loss triggered and 3 take profit triggered. Once the first take-profit is triggered, and no alert for stop-loss. Here is the script.

```
if strategy.position_size>0 and strategy.opentrades>0 
    sl_alert_price := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)-ta.atr(1)*1
    tp1_alert_price := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)+ta.atr(1)*1
    tp2_alert_price := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)+ta.atr(1)*2
    tp3_alert_price := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)+ta.atr(1)*3

if strategy.position_size<0 and strategy.opentrades>0 
    sl_alert_price := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)+ta.atr(1)*1
    tp1_alert_price := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)-ta.atr(1)*1
    tp2_alert_price := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)-ta.atr(1)*2
    tp3_alert_price := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)-ta.atr(1)*3

if longcond or shortcond or long_alert_test 
    isAlertTriggered_sl1_cond := false
    isAlertTriggered_tp1_cond := false
    isAlertTriggered_tp2_cond := false
    isAlertTriggered_tp3_cond := false 


if isAlertTriggered_sl1_cond==false and ta.cross(close,sl_alert_price) 
    alert(message= syminfo.ticker + " : SL")
    isAlertTriggered_sl1_cond := true
    isAlertTriggered_tp1_cond := true
    isAlertTriggered_tp2_cond := true
    isAlertTriggered_tp3_cond := true


if isAlertTriggered_tp1_cond==false and ta.cross(close,tp1_alert_price) 
    alert(message= syminfo.ticker + " : TP1")
    isAlertTriggered_sl1_cond := true
    isAlertTriggered_tp1_cond := true
    isAlertTriggered_tp2_cond := false
    isAlertTriggered_tp3_cond := false


if isAlertTriggered_tp2_cond==false and ta.cross(close,tp2_alert_price) 
    alert(message= syminfo.ticker + " : TP2")
    isAlertTriggered_sl1_cond := true
    isAlertTriggered_tp1_cond := true
    isAlertTriggered_tp2_cond := true
    isAlertTriggered_tp3_cond := false


if  isAlertTriggered_tp3_cond==false and ta.cross(close,tp3_alert_price)
    alert(message= syminfo.ticker + " : TP3")
    isAlertTriggered_sl1_cond := true
    isAlertTriggered_tp1_cond := true
    isAlertTriggered_tp2_cond := true
    isAlertTriggered_tp3_cond := true
```

When I use this, the alert is not generated as the rules. Sometimes TP Alert still triggered after the SL is hit. Can anyone please revise the script ? Sincerely big thanks